# Magento 1.9.2.4 Cache Problem

Tags: cache, addtocart

We have redesigned and rebuilt our site in Magento 1.9.4.2

We have released it a couple of days back, but have to make changes on a daily basis as it is very feature-rich.

Though the changes show up after we flush cache and manage the index, there are some users that just cannot add any products to cart after we are done with our processes. However, such users are able to add products to cart after they empty THEIR cache.

Is there a solution that will allow users to buy products without flushing their cache?

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like local browser caching to me rather than server side. Try sending the following headers for each page to disable browser caching.

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

Comment: Thanks Bilal and Mukesh.

My coder figured out the issue and she says it was related to cookies. She said that when users log in and log out, the cookie setting was getting disturbed.

She's fixed the issue and we're good now. Thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

please merge css files here

> System -> Configuration -> Developer -> CSS settings -> Merge CSS Files

then clear you cache from

> admin -> system -> cache management -> Flush Cache Storage
>
> admin -> system -> cache management -> Flush Magento Cache

now check it will work fine.